# NHibernate is not respecting precision and scale for creating numeric-column (for a decimal)

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the fallowing FluentNHibernate-Mapping:

```
this.Map(x => x.Discount).Precision(8).Scale(2).Not.Nullable();
```

And this is the Property in the Entity for Discount:

```
public virtual Decimal Discount { get; set; }
```

But the Schema (for SQL-Server), which NHibernate is creating, contains now:

```
Discount NUMERIC(19, 0) not null,
```

Can someone help me, what is going wrong?

Comment: Does the HBM mapping that [Fluent-NHibernate] is creating look ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Version of FNH / SQL Server are we talking about? Is there a special reason for using Precision() and Scale()? In view of reducing database size there is no mentionable benefit... My suggestion is to remove both, let NH handle this property and use a getter / Formatstring instead.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue as OP here. But I think its not really considered a "Bug" but still unexpected behavior which is not wrong.

I had a database with precision (20,2) when i query via SQL i get the value 3.00 as expected however nhibernate returned me 2.996666667.

I also found c# first rounds to 2 decimal places if you call .ToString(n2) on the value giving me the expected result of 3

Since i am running version 5.x it might be a fix they already implemented at a later stage.

For now I will make sure to increase precision in SQL to avoid this problem.